# I am facing error while creating the service for hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am creating the user for my hibernate project but I am getting the following error in my code. Please help me out with these problem.

This is my code:

```
package com.exam;

import com.exam.model.Role;
import com.exam.model.User;
import com.exam.model.UserRole;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cglib.beans.ImmutableBean;
import com.exam.service.UserService;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ExamserverApplication implements CommandLineRunner {


    private UserService userService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExamserverApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("starting...");

        User user = new User();

        user.setFirstName("avishkar");
        user.setLastName("dixit");
        user.setUsername("avi@11");
        user.setPassword("1234");
        user.setEmail("abc@gmail.com");
        user.setProfile("default.png");

        Role role1 = new Role();
        role1.setRole_id(02L);
        role1.setRole("admin");

        Set<UserRole> userRoleSet =new HashSet<>();
        UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
        userRole.setRole(role1);
        userRole.setUser(user);

        userRoleSet.add(userRole);

        User user1 = this.userService.createUser(user,userRoleSet);
        System.out.println(user1.getUsername());

    }
}
```

user service implementation as follows

```
package com.exam.service.impl;

import com.exam.model.Role;
import com.exam.model.User;
import com.exam.model.UserRole;
import com.exam.repo.RoleRepository;
import com.exam.repo.UserRepository;
import com.exam.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Set;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {


    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    //creating user
    @Override
    public User createUser(User user, Set<UserRole> userRoles) throws Exception {


        User local = this.userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
        if (local != null) {
            System.out.println("User is already there !!");
            throw new Exception();
        } else {
            //user create
            for (UserRole ur : userRoles) {
                roleRepository.save(ur.getRole());
            }

            user.getUserRoles().addAll(userRoles);
            local = this.userRepository.save(user);

        }

        return local;
    }

}
```

@Entity code is as follows
1)User

```
package com.exam.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.HashSet;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private boolean enabled=true;

    private  String profile;

    //user many roles
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "user")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

    public User(long id, String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phone, boolean enabled, String profile) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }

    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> UserRoles) {
        this.userRoles = UserRoles;
    }

    public void setProfile(String profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }

    public User()
    {

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

2)Role

```
package com.exam.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.HashSet;

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long role_id;
    private String role;

    //
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "role")
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    public Role()
    {

    }

    public Role(long roll_id, String roll) {
        this.role_id = roll_id;
        this.role = roll;
    }

    public long getRoll_id() {
        return role_id;
    }

    public void setRole_id(long roll_id) {
        this.role_id = roll_id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

userRoles

```
package com.exam.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long userRoleId;

    //user
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User user ;

    @ManyToOne
    private Role role;

    public UserRole()
    {

    }

    public long getUserRoleId() {
        return userRoleId;
    }

    public void setUserRoleId(long userRoleId) {
        this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
    }

    public com.exam.model.User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(com.exam.model.User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public com.exam.model.Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(com.exam.model.Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

the ERRORS are ass follows

```
   alter table user_role 
       add constraint FK7u21823ktfhu9bmx2350x6n8s 
       foreign key (role_role_id) 
       references roles (role_id)
2023-03-14 03:18:48.734  WARN 15348 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table user_role 
       add constraint FK7u21823ktfhu9bmx2350x6n8s 
       foreign key (role_role_id) 
       references roles (role_id)" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table user_role 
       add constraint FK7u21823ktfhu9bmx2350x6n8s 
       foreign key (role_role_id) 
       references roles (role_id)" via JDBC Statement
```

full stack trace

```
    
    alter table user_role 
       add constraint FK7u21823ktfhu9bmx2350x6n8s 
       foreign key (role_role_id) 
       references roles (role_id)
2023-03-14 03:18:48.734  WARN 15348 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table user_role 
       add constraint FK7u21823ktfhu9bmx2350x6n8s 
       foreign key (role_role_id) 
       references roles (role_id)" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table user_role 
       add constraint FK7u21823ktfhu9bmx2350x6n8s 
       foreign key (role_role_id) 
       references roles (role_id)" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:526) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:452) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at com.exam.ExamserverApplication.main(ExamserverApplication.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'FK7u21823ktfhu9bmx2350x6n8s' in the referenced table 'roles'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar:5.6.15.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

2023-03-14 03:18:48.735  INFO 15348 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-03-14 03:18:48.746  INFO 15348 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-03-14 03:18:49.395  WARN 15348 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-03-14 03:18:49.896  INFO 15348 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-14 03:18:49.907  INFO 15348 --- [           main] com.exam.ExamserverApplication           : Started ExamserverApplication in 6.589 seconds (JVM running for 7.256)
starting...
2023-03-14 03:18:49.913  INFO 15348 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-14 03:18:49.937 ERROR 15348 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at com.exam.ExamserverApplication.main(ExamserverApplication.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.exam.service.UserService.createUser(com.exam.model.User, java.util.Set)" because "this.userService" is null
    at com.exam.ExamserverApplication.run(ExamserverApplication.java:53) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    ... 5 common frames omitted

2023-03-14 03:18:49.963  INFO 15348 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-03-14 03:18:49.965  INFO 15348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-03-14 03:18:49.986  INFO 15348 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

please help me to solve these error

Comment: Your problem is in the UserRole class. You have a data modelling problem somewhere. You need to add the `com.exam.model.*` source.

Comment: Is the ‘@Id’ field of ‘@Entity’ mapped to roles table called roleId or mapped to column role_id?

Comment: Please add the ‘@Entity’ code to the question.

Comment: Why not make a proper `@ManyToMany` mapping?

Comment: Too much code. You are asking for help debugging here, not seeking answers to a question.